# Can not install older version of Electron through package.json

Tags: electron

[Since the current VS code doesn't support Electron v1.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22015), so I have to downgrade my Electron version. However, I found that I can not install the old version of Electron by giving the version number in the `package.json` file. The following is my configuration:

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./app/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^15.5.1",
    "electron": "^1.4",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

The output of the `npm install` is the following:

[image]

And I run the following command to check the version of Electron:

`node_modules/.bin/electron -v`

and the output is '1.6.2' which is the latest version of Electron.

What's more interesting is that I can install the old version of Electron successfully by directly running the following command:

`npm install electron@1.4`

So I want to if there is anything wrong in my `package.json` file which caused this problem. And if so, how can I fix it.

Comment: I noticed the vscode problem you link to has now been fixed in the nightly build (aka "insider"). I've been running the insider version for the past few days (for a different fix), and it has been solid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the Electron version 1.6 satisfies `"^1.4"` because the caret tells NPM the minimal version of the package to install.

As also written in an answer to the [Microsoft issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22015), you might use `"1.4"` or `"~1.4.0"` in order to get Electron 1.4 or any other 1.4.x version (the tilde is for minimal minor releases as shown in the [NPM documentation for the cli-based update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update) of packages).